# Is it possible to do patern binding a la Haskell in Idris?

Tags: idris

An example would be:

```
fib: Stream Integer
fib@(1::tfib) = 1 :: 1 :: [ a+b | (a,b) <- zip fib tfib]
```

But this generates the error:

```
50 | fib@(1::tfib) = 1 :: 1 :: [ a+b | (a,b) <- zip fib tfib]
   |    ^
unexpected "@(1::tfib)"
expecting "<==", "using", "with", ':', argument expression, constraint argument, expression, function right hand side, implementation
 block, implicit function argument, or with pattern
```

This doesn't look promising given that it doesn't recognize `@` at the likely position.

Note that the related concept of as-patterns works the same in Haskell and Idris:

```
growHead : List a -> List a
growHead nnl@(x::_) = x::nnl
growHead ([]) = []
```